QGIS Assign finish adding points (right-click) to keybard shortcut
In QGIS, is it possible to assign finish adding points (right-click) to a keyboard shortcut? As I 'm using a pen tablet for stream digitizing,  is quite hard to press a botton onto it to end the digitizing procedure without messing up the drawn vector.
